# Why is electron using an old version of chromium?

Tags: electron

Chromium is currently available as version 68, but electron is still using version 61.
What are the reasons for this and what are the (security) implications?

Answer (score 1):

[From electronjs's documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/security.md#chromium-security-issues-and-upgrades):

> While Electron strives to support new versions of Chromium as soon as
>   possible, developers should be aware that upgrading is a serious
>   undertaking - involving hand-editing dozens or even hundreds of files.
>   Given the resources and contributions available today, Electron will
>   often not be on the very latest version of Chromium, lagging behind by
>   either days or weeks.
>
> We feel that our current system of updating the Chromium component
>   strikes an appropriate balance between the resources we have available
>   and the needs of the majority of applications built on top of the
>   framework. We definitely are interested in hearing more about specific
>   use cases from the people that build things on top of Electron. Pull
>   requests and contributions supporting this effort are always very
>   welcome.